# OrderBy em listas<T>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, classes

Tenho uma lista `list<Pessoas>`:

minha classe pessoas:

```
public class Pessoas
{
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    public DateTime Nascimento { get; set; }
}
```

Teoricamente poderia fazer um `OrderBy` assim:

```
Pessoas.OrderBy(p => p.Nome);
```

Mas não aparece o `OrderBy` para fazer isso. Minha classe tem que 'ser' ou 'implementar' alguma coisa de `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Achei curioso que as outras respostas deram uma solução usando `List`. É isto que você quer? Ou seja, você não quer que sua própria classe guarde a lista de pessoas?

Comment: Foi isso que entendi, já que a pergunta começou com "tenho uma lista `list<Pessoas>`".

Comment: @bigown, @carlosfigueira, não quero que minha classe guarde a lista de pessoas, quero poder ordenar uma `list<Pessoas>`, passando para uma `var` ou para uma outra `list<Pessoas>`.

Comment: Eu já adaptei minha resposta dando mais informações para este caso e falando que a nomenclatura que você está usando torna confuso o que você está guardando na classe. É seu critério usar como quiser mas esta confusão mostra como nomes bem escolhidos são mais fáceis de comunicar a intenção.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, sua classe precisa implementar a interface [`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Além disto você tem que disponibilizar o *namespace* [`System.Linq`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0).

Você está chamando a classe de `Pessoas`, isto significa que ela conterá várias pessoas. Então me parece que faz sentido implementar esta interface. Mas se sua intenção é que esta classe representa só **uma** pessoa, aí não faria sentido e teria que guardar as listas de pessoas em outro objeto, talvez uma lista, como mostrado na resposta do carlosfigueira. Se sua intenção é usar uma lista para guardar as pessoas, então a lista já implementa a `IEnumerable` e você só precisaria usar o *namespace* do LINQ. Mas se for isto, o nome da classe dá uma indicação errada do que ela representa.

De qualquer forma você não pode chamar este método a partir da própria classe, como no exemplo mostrado (eu acho). Tem que ser feito com uma instância. Talvez até seja uma instância, já que C# permite que variáveis tenham nomes iguais aos tipos, mas o nome assim não dá boa indicação do que é. Então provavelmente você quer é um `var pessoas = new List<Pessoa>();`.

Como o LINQ é implementado em cima de [métodos de extensão](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), estes só estão disponíveis quando você o faz explicitamente. Ou seja, os métodos LINQ só serão consideramos parte do seu objeto se eles foram disponibilizados com `using`, caso contrário eles não aparecem no Intellisense já que eles não fazem parte do objeto, eles são definições auxiliares à parte e opcionais.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 5):

[`OrderBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/vstudio/bb534966) é um *extension method* no namespace `System.Linq`. Se você o tiver na sua lista de `using`s, então o método deve aparecer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Pessoas {
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    public DateTime Nascimento { get; set; }
}

public class Teste {
    public static void Main() {
        List<Pessoas> lista = new List<Pessoas>();
        lista.Add(new Pessoas { Nome = "Maria", Nascimento = DateTime.Today });
        lista.Add(new Pessoas { Nome = "Jose", Nascimento = DateTime.Today });
        var ordenada = lista.OrderBy(p => p.Nome);
        foreach (var pessoa in ordenada) {
            Console.WriteLine(pessoa.Nome);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Se você está usando da forma abaixo tudo o que precisa fazer é adicionar um `using System.Linq` no início do arquivo.

```
public class Pessoas
{
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    public DateTime Nascimento { get; set; }
}

var Pessoas = new List<Pessoas>();

Pessoas.OrderBy(x => x.Nome);
```

Se você estiver utilizando assim só precisa do `namespace` certo.

Answer (score 0):

```
var lOrdenada = lPessoas.OrderBy(p => p.Nome);

ou

var lOrdenada2 = (from pessoa in lPessoas orderby pessoa.Nome select pessoa).ToList();
```